# Automating adb commands via batch script

Tags: shell, batch-file, scripting, adb

is there a way to run adb shell commands via windows?

I would like to run a batch script such as this

```
adb shell 
mount -o rw,remount /system
exit
```

Currently when i run the batch script it only runs the first command `adb shell`

Any other methods is fine also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `adb shell` takes its input from stdin (e.g. the keyboard), so it won't see the subsequent commands. Instead, those will be run on your local machine as soon as `adb` exits.

`adb shell` [takes a shell command as its argument](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html), so you should be able to do:

```
adb shell "mount -o rw,remount /system"
```

The final `exit` is unnecessary in this case, because `adb` exits as soon as the command is finished.